# Why isn't this function working right?

Tags: javascript, date

I want the result to be 2018-2020. This isn't working for me. What am I missing?

Thanks

```
function todaysDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear();
  var date2 = today.getFullYear()+2;            
  var both = date +"-"+date2;
  return date;
}
```

Also this didn't do what I wanted either

```
function todaysDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = (today.getFullYear() +"-"+today.getFullYear()+2);
  return date;
}
```

Comment: "This isn't working for me" — Try providing a *clear problem statement*. What does "isn't working" mean? Do you get an error? Do you get a result you don't expect?

Comment: Stackoverflow allows you to [embed a live demo of JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) into your question. You should do that!

Comment: To begin with, you do several calculations just to discard them.

Comment: Try `var date = today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getFullYear() + 2);`

Comment: "dummy user" - this must be a test

Comment: possibly the worst title for any question on SO ever

Comment: As an aside calling a function `todaysDate` when it returns a concatenated string of two years is not a useful idea for anyone who might call the function thinking it returns today's date.

Comment: You are returning the wrong variable, return variable named "both" not the "date" in 1st function  and for 2nd function you try var date = (today.getFullYear()+"-"+(today.getFullYear()+2));  this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code itself in your first attempt works, apart from the last line. Right now you just return the first date and ignore the second one and the combined string of dates. I expect you intended to return the string which shows both dates.

```
return both;
```

should solve your problem. Demo:

```js
function todaysDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear();
  var date2 = today.getFullYear()+2;
  var both = date +"-"+date2;
  return both;
}
console.log(todaysDate());
```

Possibly it was just a typo or oversight.

I would also consider giving your function a better name, because it doesn't actually return today's date.

Answer (score 1):

The first function is not working because you are returning wrong var.

```
function todaysDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear();
  var date2 = today.getFullYear()+2;            
  var both = date +"-"+date2;
  return both;
}
```

the second is not working because you are doing bad concatination

```
function todaysDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = (today.getFullYear() +"-"+ (today.getFullYear()+2)); //extra brackets for maintaining int value instead of concatinating
  return date;
}
```

Comment: hey. i am suing ur paytm package. i have done evrythng as u said. but wen i click the pay now button the page shows "transaction being processed" and then redirects me to a blank page like payment/api/status. why is it not taking me to paytm website?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are getting a string when you concatenate. Please parse it to integer

ie,

```
function todaysDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = (today.getFullYear() +"-"+ (parseInt(today.getFullYear())+2));
  return date;
}
```

Comment: No need to parse. Without parsing it also works well.

Comment: `today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getFullYear() + 2)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your first function doesn't return what you want. Try

```
function todaysDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear();
  var date2 = today.getFullYear()+2;            
  var both = date +"-"+date2;
  return both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, should do it

```
function todaysDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = (Number(today.getFullYear()) +"-"+Number(today.getFullYear()+2));
  return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first Example will work, you return date instead of both

```
function todaysDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear();
  var date2 = today.getFullYear()+2;            
  var both = date +"-"+date2;
  return both;
}
```

Comment: return the "both" variable not the "date" variable